# На странице "Что такое Мета" заменить ссылку на поиск

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка, мета, ссылки

На странице [«Что такое Мета»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) нужно заменить ссылку на поиск.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас ссылка ведёт на страницу поиска на основном сайте нужно заменить на: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Такая же проблема у японского SO, кстати.

Comment: @alexolut  Поправил и на SOja.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как ответ оформите, чтоб зааксептить можно было)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв. Поправил в нашей справке и в справке SOja.